# Container won't spread out out items

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

Having an issue with my cards within a container. They won't spread out to the 100% width of the header so they're even. This is a weather dashboard app and I want the container containing the 5 cards to be the same width of the header and to wrap when on mobile. Any help appreciated. Below is my HTML and CSS:

Here is the HTML. I have a total of 5 cards within the container div.

```
<body>
    <header>
      <h1> Weather Dashboard </h1>
      <p id="currentDay"> </p>
      <input type="text" class="searchBox" placeholder="City Search">
      <!-- Hidden Recent Searches Bar with Bootstrap -->
      <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal-sm" hidden>
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="btnContainer">
          <button class= "goBtn"> Go</button>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Cards for weather forecast with Bootstrap -->
    <div class = "container">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
          <p class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
          <p class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
header {
    background: rgb(255,255,255, 0.35);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    width: 90%;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
}

.card {
    background: rgb(255,255,255, 0.75);
    font-family: all-round-gothic, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're setting the width of each card to `18em` in the HTML.

Comment: I tried taking that off and it didn't do anything either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS Bootstrap to space out the elements evenly. Since Bootstrap uses 12 columns, you can have a 1 column margin on each side and have each card take up 2 columns:

```
<div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-2 offset-1 mt-5 text-center">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-2 mt-5 text-center">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-2 mt-5 text-center">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-2 mt-5 text-center">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-2 mt-5 text-center">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
                      <p class="card-text"></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, you also need to comment out your .container{} CSS as it interferes with the Bootstrap.

The end result will look something like this:

[image]

The 5 blank boxes at the bottom are your cards.

Comment: Thanks! New to bootstrap but I kinda remember this concept but wasn't sure how to do it. Thanks so much

Comment: No problem :D happy to help

Comment: You can also use the `.col` class to have all cols equally spaced, without having to specify the exact width.

Comment: How do you set it to equally space?

Comment: Actually, I'm not 100% sure. I thought I knew what Quasipickle meant but I tried it and it didn't work. But, I do recall that there is a way to space elements equally with the grid system